# MySQL. Numeric sort by string ID

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating live score for dragracing competition.
I've got table in database

```
id      time
k2      16,010
k4      15,11
k25     15,819
k26     15,114
z27     19,696
```

I need to get that table in reverse order by `id`.
For example, if select `SELECT id FROM online order by id desc` the result would be sorted as a `string`.

```
id
k9
k8
k7
k6
k5
k4
k3
k17
k16
k15
k14
```

I need 17-14-9-4

**Upd.**
THANKS FOR ALL!!!
This one helped

```
SELECT CAST( replace( id, 'k', '' ) AS SIGNED ) AS sort
FROM online
ORDER BY `sort` DESC
```

Comment: In your result I don't see z27. How do you want to handle different letters in your sorting?

Comment: Is a17 > b16 ? Is the number or letter more important?

Comment: Is the structure consistent? I.e., always one and only one letter followed by nothing but digits?

Comment: What about k25 and k26? Should those be first?

Comment: 'k' and 'z' are letters for several types of competition. Since there is no chance to sort it in numeric order, I'd separate that latter in another column. Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventlyally get this :)

```
SELECT CAST( replace( id, 'k', '' ) AS SIGNED ) AS sort
FROM online
ORDER BY `sort` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the field into two, one with the "k" and another with the number.

Alternatively, less preferable, if you use PHP, you can use the `nat_sort()` method or, probably, `usort()` using the `strnatcmp()` function for comparing this particular field.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your schema. You should have a column for the letter part. Then you can do

```
SELECT CONCAT(letter, id) FROM online ORDER BY id ASC
```

Except you should name `letter` something descriptive.

**EDIT:** If the letter is important in the sorting (it's not clear whether it is or not) then you would do:

```
SELECT CONCAT(letter, id) FROM online ORDER BY letter, id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the structure is consistent with a single letter followed by digits, you could do something like:

```
Select ...
From online
Order By Substring(Id, 1, 1) Desc
    , Cast( Substring(Id, 2, Len(id)) As int ) Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort it that way, ether add a 0 (k09 - k04) or add another field that is an int.