# Numeric sort the values as Strings in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering if there is a way to do a numeric sort when the number is a string. Take a look at example:

The query:

> SELECT * FROM t_tables t order by id_string asc

This is the list from DB:

```
13
4
6
8
10
1
3
2
5
12
7
9
11
```

I need to extract it in this way:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

But as result I get this:

```
1
10
11
12
13
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that you always have numeric values in the column you can use the [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) operator. Also have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782672/mysql-numeric-sort-by-string-id).

```
SELECT * FROM t_tables t ORDER BY CAST(id_string AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM t_tables t order by cast(id_string as signed integer) asc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps:

```
SELECT * FROM t_tables t order by cast(id_string as unsigned)
```